# How do I get this editmodal.js to update properties of an item into a database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express

I'm working on developing a retail shelftalker management webapp using node.js, Express, and react. I think I've come some long way only using ChatGPT and very little coding experience. so here lies the lack of debugging experience as I have no clue what to do and chatGPT stopped giving any good solutions.

So I have a productlist.js which fetches all the products from a MongoDB database. Adding products using the productform.js works fine as well. Tested on front-end and with Postman. I'm stuck at getting an editproductmodal.js to work properly. The issue is that whenever I fetch a product into the modal, product properties are imported, however when trying to edit the properties it just renders the initial value instantly and does not hold the value I want to change to until I press the save button.

If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated. I am a beginner with coding so I've had this bug for a few days now, cannot get over it, hence I'm asking for help here...

Here's my code:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import EditProductModal from './EditProductModal';

  function ProductList() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [editingProduct, setEditingProduct] = useState(null);
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
    const [categoryFilter, setCategoryFilter] = useState(''); // New state for category filter

    // Function to fetch products with optional search, sorting, and category filtering
    const fetchAndSetProducts = async () => {
        try {
            const query = new URLSearchParams();
            if (searchTerm) query.append('search', searchTerm);
            if (categoryFilter) query.append('category', categoryFilter); // Add category filter to the query

            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/products?${query.toString()}`);
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            const data = await response.json();
            setProducts(data);
        } catch (e) {
            setError(e.message);
        }
    };

    // Fetch products when component mounts and when search or sorting changes
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAndSetProducts();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps, no-undef
    }, [searchTerm, categoryFilter]);
    
    // Function to handle edit button click
    const handleEditClick = (productId) => {
        const productToEdit = products.find(p => p._id === productId);
        if (productToEdit) {
            setEditingProduct({ ...productToEdit });
        }
    };

    const handleModalClose = () => {
        setEditingProduct(null);
    };

    const handleSaveChanges = async updatedProduct => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/products/${updatedProduct._id}`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(updatedProduct),
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
            }

            fetchProducts(); // Re-fetch products to update the list
            handleModalClose(); // Close the modal
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("Failed to update product:", e.message);
            setError(e.message);
        }
    };

    // Function to fetch products
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/products');
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            const data = await response.json();
            setProducts(data);
        } catch (e) {
            setError(e.message);
        }
    };

    // Function to delete a product
    const deleteProduct = async (productId) => {
        if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this product?")) {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/products/${productId}`, {
                    method: 'DELETE'
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
                }

                // Update the product list after deletion
                setProducts(products.filter(product => product._id !== productId));
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("Failed to delete product:", e.message);
                setError(`Failed to delete product: ${e.message}`);
            }
        }
    };

    // Fetch products on component mount
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAndSetProducts();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps, no-undef
    }, [searchTerm, categoryFilter]);

    if (error) {
        return <div>Error fetching products: {error}</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Product List</h2>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search products..."
                value={searchTerm}
                onChange={e => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
            />
            <select value={categoryFilter} onChange={e => setCategoryFilter(e.target.value)}>
                <option value="">All Categories</option>
                <option value="Bread">Bread</option>
                <option value="Cakes">Cakes</option>
                <option value="Sandwiches">Sandwiches</option>
                <option value="Hot Food">Hot Food</option>
                <option value="Pastry">Pastry</option>
                <option value="FOS POS">FOS POS</option>
            </select>
            <ul>
                {products.map(product => (
                    <li key={product._id}>
                        <Link to={`/products/${product._id}`}>{product.name}</Link> - ${product.price}
                        <button onClick={() => deleteProduct(product._id)}>Delete</button>
                        <button onClick={() => handleEditClick(product._id)}>Edit</button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <EditProductModal 
                product={editingProduct} 
                onClose={handleModalClose} 
                onSave={handleSaveChanges} 
            />
            {error && <div className="error-message">{error}</div>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductList;`
```

Comment: you need to add the `EditProductModal` code, the problem i can tell without seeing your code is probably related to the inputs you're using maybe some contradiction with these props : `defaultValue` `Value` or something